# Where are the RETURN TABLE columns in the information schema?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo (_id INT) RETURNS TABLE (id INT, my_name TEXT, adt_date DATE) ...
```

I desire to return

---

```
_________________
id      | INT
my_name | TEXT
adt_date| DATE
```

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.routines AS r
LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters AS p ON r.specific_name = p.specific_name
ORDER BY r.routine_name
       , p.ordinal_position;
```

To my chagrin, I was unable to find the column names in this query for RETURN TABLE functions.
What am I missing here?

Not that it probably matters in this case, but I am running PG 9.6

Comment: I have come to the realization that the use of `OUT` parameters is the same thing as using a `RETURNS TABLE.`

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems correct, so I'm not really sure what your question is? I created a function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION twice (x int) 
   RETURNS TABLE (y int, z text) 
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT x, 'a' UNION ALL SELECT x, 'a' ;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and asked the catalog for:

```
SELECT r.routine_name, p.parameter_mode, p.parameter_name, p.data_type 
FROM information_schema.routines r 
LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters AS p 
    ON r.specific_name = p.specific_name 
WHERE r.routine_name = 'twice';

routine_name    parameter_mode  parameter_name  data_type
twice           IN              x               integer
twice           OUT             y               integer
twice           OUT             z               text
```

Is it something that I did miss in your question?

Comment: you did not. I thought those were specifically `OUT` parameters.